# How to make *ngFor work with an ObservableArray in Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, ngfor, nativescript-angular

An `ObservableArray` works fine with `<ListView [items]="feedsComments"`, where `feedsComments` is an `ObservableArray`in NativeScript.

But when I replace the `ListView` with the following:

```
<StackLayout *ngFor="let item of feedsComments">
</StackLayout>
```

It throws the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object],[object Object]' of type 'object'.
NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

Comment: Looks like the code went missing.
Works fine with <ListView [items]="feedsComments"></ListView>
Does not work with 
<StackLayout *ngFor="let item of feedsComments"></StackLayout>

Comment: If you want to pass through a regular *ngFor, you need to first convert the nativescript ObservableArray to a regular array. Otherwise, you need to use an ng-template inside a custom component that handles the list for you (which is what the ListView component is doing anyway).

Answer (score 1):

```
<StackLayout *ngFor="let item of feedsComments._array" height="100" width="100">
    <Label [text]="item.someField"></Label> 
</StackLayout>
```

Ugly, but it works. Seems that the class can do with a getItems() method. There is a getItem(i) though to get a specific item in the array.